# How to save/print without displaying in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a problem with displaying my results in Matlab. According to my task, the script computes more than 200 plots so displaying them is difficult for my computer. I have decided to save the results without displaying.

As example:

```
figure('visible', 'off');
plot(1:10,rand(1,10))
figure('visible', 'off');
plot(1:10,rand(1,10))

...
figure('visible', 'off');
plot(1:10,rand(1,10))
```

To print them I am creating a list:

```
list_of_plots = findobj(allchild(0), 'flat', 'Type', 'figure');
```

and using a loop to print/save them

```
dstr = datestr(now, 'dd-mmm-yyyy_HHMMSS');
for iFig = 1:length(FigList)
  FigHandle = FigList(iFig);
  set(0, 'CurrentFigure', FigHandle);
  fileNamefig = [dstr, '_',flname, '_Num',  num2str(10),'_h', num2str(iFig), '.jpg'];
  print(FigHandle, '-djpeg','-r600',['folder_adress',fileNamefig])
end
```

The script saves/prints them but it displays them too....why does it happens? `figure('visible', 'off');` is it wrong?

Comment: That *should* work. But why not save each figure when you plot it, and then close it again (or reuse the figure for the next plot)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, your question provides good context, but is lacking a `mcve`. For instance if I create a figure, get a handle using `findobj`, and print that figure, it all works without making the figure visible. If you had a minimal example showing otherwise, that would be helpful. Cris's suggestion is a good one, and would minimise the risk of creating hundreds of invisible figures, which will slow MATLAB down eventually and use lots of memory - you should at least delete the figure when you're done printing.

Comment: instead of printing, you can also call Matlab's *Figure export* with this snippet `s = hgexport('readstyle',ExpStyl); s.Format = 'jpeg'; 
 hgexport(fh,FileName,s);` (of course, you need to specify a style ;) )